# cc compiler and cache

Tags: c, macos, algorithm, cc

I was wasting a lot of time figuring out why an algorithm that should be more efficient than another one, however, was perfectly the same in terms of speed to the other. I did these operations: I compiled the first source code in a separate terminal window; while the second source code in another window. I simply used a:

$ cc number_v1.c

to compile the first, and a:

$ cc number_v2.c

for the second source code.
I'm on Mac OS X Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0: Tue Aug 20 16:57:14 PDT 2019; root: xnu-4903.271.2 ~ 2 / RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64.

In response I had exactly the same timing result. Something impossible given the best algorithm of the second source code.

Then I turn everything off and try again the next day. To my surprise I finally see the differences: the second source code is completed in a much shorter time than the first.
It seems that the first time the compiler did not compile the code of the listing and indeed, perhaps still considered the old version; consider that I have tried to modify the source code several times with relative compilation, but as a result always the same.

It happened to me a while ago working on another source code (with relative loss of time).
Unfortunately, the event is not replicable and does not occur frequently.

Can anyone explain why it happened? Is there a kind of cache to be reset in these cases?

Their respective source codes follow; it's about finding the prime numbers from 2 to 1000000.

```
/* cc number_v1.c */    

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i, j, n = 1000000;

    for(i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        for(j = 2; j < i && i % j != 0; j++)
            ;

        if(j >= i) printf("%d ", j);    
    }           
    return 0;
}



/* cc number_v2.c */

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i, j, n = 1000000;

    for(i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        for(j = 2; j * j <= i && i % j != 0; j++)
            ;

        if(j * j > i) printf("%d ", i); 
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The very first thing you need to do if you want to compare running times is to compile with optimization enabled.  Try `cc -O2 <source>`.

Comment: If you don't use the `-o` option, both commands are putting the executable in the same `a.out` file. If you do both compilations at the same time in different windows, the result is whichever compilation took longer.

Comment: One thing I forgot to write is that the source files reside in different folders

Comment: There is no timing code in this - how did you measure the performance?  How long did it take?

Comment: I suspect that you ran the same code twice - put each algorithm in the same executable and include the timing in the code.  If an experiment  gives "impossible" results, you should first check your method.  Then if you want others to check your method, you have to describe it and show the evidence for your results.

Answer (score 1):

You should include the measurement in your code.  There is clearly something wrong with your measurement and you need to clearly show your method.

I performed the following test modified to use `uint64_t` to prevent arithmetic overflow in `alg1()`, and also replacing the `printf()` output with a volatile sink:

```
{volatile uint64_t x = i ;}
```

Measuring the performance of an algorithm containing I/O can be misleading - you may be measuring the I/O performance of your system.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define MAX 1000000 ;
void alg1( void )
{
    uint64_t i, j, n = MAX;

    for( i = 2; i <= n; i++ )
    {
        for( j = 2; j < i && i % j != 0; j++ )
            ;

        if( j >= i ){volatile uint64_t x = i ;}
    }
}


void alg2( void )
{
    uint64_t i, j, n = MAX;

    for( i = 2; i <= n; i++ )
    {
        for( j = 2; j * j <= i && i % j != 0; j++ )
            ;

        if( j * j > i ){volatile uint64_t x = i ;}
    }
}


int main()
{
    clock_t start = clock() ;
    alg1() ;
    int alg1_clocks = clock() - start ;

    start = clock() ;
    alg2() ;
    int alg2_clocks = clock() - start ;

    printf( "\nalg1() took %f seconds", (double)(alg1_clocks) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC ) ;
    printf( "\nalg2() took %f seconds", (double)(alg2_clocks) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC ) ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

Result:

```
alg1() took 336.681000 seconds
alg2() took 0.621000 seconds
```

So your results cannot be reproduced so I would doubt their integrity.

Comment: The reason for which I did not enter the measurement time is that it seems clear to me that the second algorithm is much more powerful than the first. ... The fact is that it already happened to me a few weeks ago ... I made a copy paste with BBedit of the code in a new file and from here I started to modify the code compiling it later; I noticed that despite having put on a showy printf ("HEEEYYY"), he didn't show me that word. I continued to compile (the same file) until it "took" the changes. The source code I remembered had also modified it with viand still didn't take it...

Comment: I continued to compile (the same file) until it "get" the changes. The source code I remembered had also modified it with vi (the command line editing program) and still didn't take it. reason why it came to my mind that it could be a cached event / process. When you turned on the computer, if you noticed, the compiler is a little slow in creating the executable code, but once started after the first time it turns out to be very fast ... I don't know why but this leads me to always think of a cache that is whimsical.

Comment: @RobertoRocco Compiler's do not work in such a non-deterministic fashion.  You save the file to the filesystem, and the compiler compiles the file.  This sounds like operator error to me.

Comment: I hope so that it is my mistake, because not trusting your compiler would mean putting in doubt everything you write

Answer (score 0):

First of all the output of the codes most probably aren't identical but you didn't check. `j * j` does not fit in a 32-bit int with numbers larger than 46340, so undefined behaviour is a possibility, but I do not believe that it is the reason here.

The first code executes the inner loop *O(i)* times whereas the 2nd executes the inner loop *O(i<sup>1/2</sup>*) times, hence this is the difference between *O(<sup>n²</sup>)*  and *O(<sup>3n/2</sup>)*, which at 1000000 would mean 316-fold execution time for the former (my computer gives 89 s vs 0.20 which is bout ~446 fold difference which is close enough), and that with `-O3`.

That you got the same *low* times would have been impossibru, unless the compilation took 89 seconds to inline the code. I.e. you didn't run the first program then.

Comment: It happened to me some time ago that the compiler did not take into account the changes made to the code. after several failed attempts I managed to compile, for this reason it could be a kind of cache ..

Comment: @RobertoRocco You mean you ran the compiler but forgot to save the changes to the source file.  That is the only plausible explanation.  If you are using an IDE or editor with a feature to launch the compiler, it may not be configured to save the file when you compile.  The compiler works in the content of the file, not what happens to be in the editor.